# Why do computer graphics applications use piecewise polynomial curves of degree 3 rather than curves of higher-order, say degree 100?

Tags: graphics, curves, beziers, splines

just wondering why is that? can't get my head around it. wouldn't the use of degree 100 be better? I'm really new to this stuff.

Comment: The more math you have to do, the longer it takes. Cubic Beziers are perfectly adequate for visualization.

Answer (score 5):

the higher the degree the more parameters you have to tweak. For example for a 100 point bezier curve there are 100 points to tweak and each point affects *every* part of the *entire* bezier curve, a piecewise curve lets you localize any tweaks you want to make.

The higher degree the more intricate the calculations, degree 100 in a polynomial equation means you need to raise a number to the 100th power. This can lead to numeric instability or those terms are meaningless anyway.

A cubic polynomial has enough flexibility to give you a curve match on transitions between adjoining curve. This is good enough that you can hide the transition between subsequent bits in.

Answer (score 0):

You use whatever fits the job.

If you need code to do arbitrary degree in term of Bézier curves, here it is:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785097/how-do-i-implement-a-bézier-curve-in-c
vector_4 getBezierPoint(vector<vector_4> points, float t)
{
    size_t i = points.size() - 1;

    while (i > 0)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            points[k].x += t * (points[k + 1].x - points[k].x);
            points[k].y += t * (points[k + 1].y - points[k].y);
            points[k].z += t * (points[k + 1].z - points[k].z);
            points[k].w += t * (points[k + 1].w - points[k].w);
        }

        i--;
    }

    return points[0];
}
```

Comment: The picture seems irrelevant to the question and to the answer ..

Comment: I’ll delete the picture.